# Why are my uninitialised variables working?

Tags: javascript

I'm making a timer with two stages and I've forgotten to initialise some variables in a function I was giving to my timer object.  Yet it seems to work with no problems.

With for example, timerObj.startTime, I know that I'm adding it to the object and defining it there and then inside timerObj.start().  Yet currentTime, minutesLeft and secondLeft which I haven't prefixed with timerObj still work completely fine without being defined globally or within the interval function.  Are these being treated in the same way as timerObj.startTime?

```
var timerObj = {workDuration : 60000, breakDuration : 60000, currentPhase : "work"};

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    document.getElementsByTagName("button")[4].addEventListener("click", timerObj.start);
    document.getElementsByTagName("button")[5].addEventListener("click", timerObj.stop);
    document.getElementsByTagName("button")[6].addEventListener("click", timerObj.pause);
});

timerObj.changeTime = function(durationType, durationChange) {
    return timerObj[durationType] = timerObj[durationType] + durationChange;
};

timerObj.start = function() {
    timerObj.startTime = new Date().getTime();
    if (timerObj.timeLeftOnPause === undefined){
        timerObj.timeLeftOnPause = timerObj[timerObj.currentPhase + "Duration"];
    }
    timerInterval = setInterval(timerObj.interval, 100);
};

timerObj.interval = function() {
    currentTime = new Date().getTime() - timerObj.startTime;
    timerObj.timeLeft = timerObj.timeLeftOnPause - currentTime;
    minutesLeft = numberDecorator(Math.floor(Math.ceil(timerObj.timeLeft / 100) / 600));
    secondsLeft = numberDecorator(Math.floor((Math.ceil(timerObj.timeLeft / 100) / 10) % 60));
    displayTime = minutesLeft + " : " + secondsLeft;
    document.getElementsByClassName(timerObj.currentPhase + "-timer-display")[0].innerHTML = displayTime;
    if (currentTime >= timerObj.timeLeftOnPause) {
        timerObj.stop();
        timerObj.currentPhase === "work" ? timerObj.currentPhase = "break" : timerObj.currentPhase = "work"; 
        if (timerObj.currentPhase === "break"){
            timerObj.start();
        }
    }
    return timerObj.timeLeft;
};

timerObj.pause = function(){
    timerObj.timeLeftOnPause = timerObj.timeLeft;
    clearInterval(timerInterval);
}

timerObj.stop = function() {
    clearInterval(timerInterval);
    timerObj.timeLeftOnPause = timerObj.workDuration;
    document.getElementsByClassName(timerObj.currentPhase + "-timer-display")[0].innerHTML = 
    numberDecorator(timerObj[timerObj.currentPhase + "Duration"] / 60000) + " : 00";
};
```

Comment: uninitialised variables are automatically initialised as *global variables* in non-strict mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because if you assign anything to a non-existing variable, that variable will be automatically declared on the global scope... unless you are using `use strict`.

Comment: Oh.  I don't know how I've got stage of my learning (a few months) without knowing that.  Can I assume this is bad practice?

Comment: It almost always means you forgot to declare your variable, which is a mistake.

Comment: One last question, am I right in saying that my timerObj.startTime isn't global because I added it to the object?  Thanks for clearing this up.

Comment: Yep, that's right. Anything with a dot in it isn't global.

Comment: Thank you!  I will accept answer when the site lets me.